# How to access Tomcat on a specific IP address?

Tags: tomcat

I have created a windows instance at amazon lightsail. I have installed tomcat 8 on it. Now I want to run tomcat using IP address of that instance, like 19.8.123.7:8080. How can I configure it?

Comment: you do not have to configure it, just start it

Comment: when i am putting ip:portnumber at URL it is showing "this page is not working" message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Tomcat listen to 19.8.123.7 address.
If you want it to listen to all interfaces (IP-s) just remove "address=" from Connector string in your configuration file and restart Tomcat.

Or just use your IP to listen to that address address=19.8.123.7 in the Connector string

Comment: I have putted. but "This site can't reached" this message is showing

Comment: Did you restart Tomcat after inputting the IP ...?it should work

Comment: yes. I have restarted it. but it is showing that error.

Comment: You need to edit server.xml file.

Open up the Server.xml file and search for Connector.

The top Connector will have the port that you're trying to communicate through, in my case 8080. In between port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" type address="0.0.0.0" (Line will look like port="8080" address="0.0.0.0" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192").

Cheers!

Comment: i have tried like above way, but tomcat is not running on IP.